# Surface Energy Density and Integral

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

How would I derive the Electric Field on a square surface, which has continuous distribution of charge, given that I know the surface charge density is a function of two variables $\sigma(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are positions on the square surface. My understanding is that the potential is given as $$\phi(r)=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon r}$$

Therefore, I would have to take the double integral of the $\sigma(x,y)$ function to calculate charge at an $x,y$ position on the surface and then take the partial derivatives (required by problem $\mathbf E=-\boldsymbol \nabla\phi$) to arrive at the electric field at that point. However, when I take the partial derivatives with respect to x and y, what position am I referencing / comparing to? $r$ is the distance from the charge, but in this case, there is continuous distribution of charge across, so I am confused as to how I would calculate the electric field via partial derivatives. Or did I mess up by calculating charge as such $$q=\int\limits_{0}^{x}\int\limits_{0}^{y}\sigma(x,y)dxdy.$$

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, you inserted the total charge $$q_\text{tot}=\int_\Sigma \sigma(x,y) dx dy$$ of the surface $\Sigma$ into the formular for the electric potential of a point charge: $$\phi(r)= \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon r}.$$ However, the formular you obtain that way is valid under the assumption that we can treat the surface $\Sigma$ as a point charge, i.e. in the large distance limit (large compared to the extension of $\Sigma$). To obtain a valid formular for the potential of the surface, you use $$\phi(\vec r) =\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon} \int_\Sigma \frac{\sigma(\vec r^\prime)}{|\vec r - \vec r^\prime|}d\vec r^\prime,$$ where the integral parameter $\vec r^\prime$ runs over all points of the surface. Think of it as the superposition of all the infinitesimal point charges $\sigma(\vec r^\prime)$ at the point $\vec r$. Note that - in contrast to $\vec r^\prime$ - the point $\vec r$ is not confined to the surface. The electric field is obtained applying the gradient $\vec\nabla$.

In the case at hand this means $$\phi(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon} \int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\int_{-b/2}^{b/2} \frac{\sigma(x^\prime,y^\prime)}{\sqrt{(x-x^\prime)^2 + (y-y^\prime)^2 + z^2}} dx^\prime dy^\prime,$$ where I used a different coordinization of the square to make use of its symmetry. Again, $(x,y,z)$ is the point in space we want the electric potential and $(x^\prime, y^\prime)$ (or if you prefer $(x^\prime,y^\prime,0)$ ) describes a point on the surface.

I hope this could help you. Cheers!

Comment: Hey @Johnny Longsom, thanks for responding. Your explanation did help unpack that confusion I'm currently having. So, from my understanding then, in the last question, the points $x',y'$ refer to all other points on the surface? I'm not sure what you mean by how the integral parameter runs over all points of the surface in terms of actually calculating the integral. Shouldn't the integral be looking at a singular x,y point?

Comment: The variables $x^\prime$ and $y^\prime$ are integral parameters that parametrize the surface you want to integrate. That's what I intended to say by "running over the surface". In case af a simple square surface the integral takes the form stated in my answer. To solve the integral you first have to specify the charge density $\sigma$.
I don't quite understand what you mean by "looking at a singular point".